# Find a certain sequence of numbers in a row of Excel data

Tags: excel

I am analysing some data in `Excel` where the results are shown in rows of cells, such as follows:

`0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1`
`0 0 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -2`

(for both examples above lets say first cell is A1)

I am looking for help to find a formula can identify where a sequence in any row goes from either -1 to 0 or -1 to -2, and the result returns either a 1 for true and a 0 for false. Any help with this appreciated!

Comment: The issue you have here is handling the zeros. In your examples should both lines return false? When you say goes from are you meaning, for the second example that the smallest value is -2 and the largest is 0 (failing your criteria) OR are these in order and then the first value is 0 and the last value is -2 (again failing your criteria). Either way I can't see logically how either of your examples passes either of the criteria unless you're planning to test with one including zeros and one not

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return false for the first example and true for the second. I am assuming your first example is in A1:L1 and your second is in A2:L2

```
=OR(AND(INDEX(A1:L1,,1)=-1, INDEX(A1:L1,,COUNT(A1:L1))=0), AND(INDEX(A1:L1,,MATCH(1, --(A1:L1<>0),0))=-1,INDEX(A1:L1,,COUNT(A1:L1))=-2))*1
```

This needs to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

However, I don't think your criteria is a logical test as logically both of these should fail (I'm assuming you've provided at least one example of your data that should pass)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Appreciate the response Tom, thank you!